# Transition on :before (background-color)

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm appplying a class to the body when an element is active at my site. I want to fade out the remaining content very much like a modal, but I'd like to fade in the background-overlay which I havent succeeded with so far.

```css
.booking-open{
  transition:background-color 2s ease;
}

.booking-open:before{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  content:"";
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5); 

}
```

```html
<body class="booking-open">
Demo
</body>
```

I've tried almost every scenario, but so far not the right one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 animations like this:

```
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: inherit;}
    to {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);}
}

.booking-open:before{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  content:"";
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/193w5pyz/1/